# App Script Google sheet - button for pasting data values simple form

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, button, simple-form

at the beginning I immediately inform you that I am totally green in appscript

I would need a script that pasted values into the appropriate sheets and searches for the appropriate criteria to paste the values into the appropriate cells

explains exactly what I mean
I know that there is such a thing as a google form but it does not meet my expectations, below is created a so-called form.

cell B tells you what Shift they need to fill out the form the same cell C shows which area to fill it

```
D3 = current day
E3 = what a shift
F3 = what area
```

in column G, not all fields are filled in by Inbound or Outbound
[image]

and I would like the person filling out the form to click the Send button after clicking, the script would search for the date in the form, shift and area, then the script would enter the data into the appropriate tabs and shift

[image]

my bookmarks
in each tab there is a report divided into days and data
I can't describe it that's why we put a link to google sheet so you can go in and see

[Google-Sheet AppScript](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c59trhM2dP00NchygkW_K-hTkQWA904pOm1ciMXFhGU/edit?usp=sharing)

but i'll try to be brief
I fill out the form on 30/03/2023 on the Yellow shift in the Inbound area, cells `G4:G12, G14:G17, G20:G21, G26:G27` after filling them out, I click send and paste them to the "Inbound" tab shift "Yellow" and on the appropriate date

Comment: In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your current script and the current issue of your script?

Comment: @Tanaike
you already have a script in the file, I didn't have it at first

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

I took the time to paste it in your sheet for you to test the button. Let me know if that works.

```
function myFunction() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form");
  var inboundSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Inbound");
  var outboundSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Outbound");

  var date = form.getRange("D3").getValue().toLocaleDateString({year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' });
  var shift = form.getRange("E3").getValue();
  var area = form.getRange("F3:G3").getValue();
  var dateFinder = inboundSheet.createTextFinder(date).matchCase(true).findNext();

  var inboundRanges = form.getRangeList(["G4:G8", "G9:G12","G14:G17","G20:G21","G26:G27"]).getRanges();
  var outboundRanges = form.getRangeList(["G4:G12","G9:G12", "G18","G22:G24","G28:G29"]).getRanges();

  switch(shift)
  {
    case "Yellow":
    if(area=="Inbound")
    {
      inboundSheet.getRange(66, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[0].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[0].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(73, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[1].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[1].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(80, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[2].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[2].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(86, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[3].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[3].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(92, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[4].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[4].getValues());
    }
    else
    {
      if(area=="Outbound")
      {
        for(var i=0; i<outboundRanges.length; i++)
        {
          outboundSheet.getRange(66, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[0].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[0].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(73, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[1].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[1].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(84, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[2].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[2].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(88, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[3].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[3].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(94, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[4].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[4].getValues());
        }
      }
    }
    break;

    case "Brown":
    if(area=="Inbound")
    {
      inboundSheet.getRange(35, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[0].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[0].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(42, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[1].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[1].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(49, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[2].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[2].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(55, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[3].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[3].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(61, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[4].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[4].getValues());
    }
    else
    {
      if(area=="Outbound")
      {
        for(var i=0; i<outboundRanges.length; i++)
        {
          outboundSheet.getRange(35, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[0].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[0].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(42, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[1].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[1].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(49, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[2].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[2].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(55, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[3].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[3].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(61, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[4].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[4].getValues());
        }
      }
    }
    break;

    case "Dark":
    if(area=="Inbound")
    {
      inboundSheet.getRange(97, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[0].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[0].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(104, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[1].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[1].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(111, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[2].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[2].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(117, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[3].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[3].getValues());
      inboundSheet.getRange(123, dateFinder.getColumn(), inboundRanges[4].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(inboundRanges[4].getValues());
    }
    else
    {
      if(area=="Outbound")
      {
        for(var i=0; i<outboundRanges.length; i++)
        {
          outboundSheet.getRange(97, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[0].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[0].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(104, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[1].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[1].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(111, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[2].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[2].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(117, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[3].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[3].getValues());
          outboundSheet.getRange(125, dateFinder.getColumn(), outboundRanges[4].getValues().flat().length, 1).setValues(outboundRanges[4].getValues());
        }
      }
    }
    break;
  };
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getColumn')

Comment: I added a script so you can check for errors yourself

and thank you for your time

Comment: @VoDAyToN Let me check and try to troubleshoot the error. I made a copy of your sheet before and it is working there.

Comment: when I use the button, line number 8 pops up, but when I run the script in Appscript, it works but adds values on the previous day

Comment: I was just testing the button and it is working. Seems like it is adding the values correctly to the sheet.

Comment: How are your time settings configured in Google Sheets? Have you defined a timezone at  File>Settings>Time zone?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252887/discussion-between-vodayton-and-fernando-lara).

Comment: check chat when you will

Comment: are you able to help me because this script does not work properly, the button works only for me and for inntch it crashes an error '.getColumn() pos.23'